# Google Drive APIs call fail with permission denied on iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken

Tags: c#, google-api, permissions, google-drive-api, google-iam

I'm trying to use the Google Drive APIs to upload a file (C# SDK). This is a background service so I have created a service account to perform the upload.

short story, I am getting the following error:

"Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist)"

I have looked over roles and permissions ad-nauseum.  What am I missing?

**Details**

I and given it the following roles (among others) granted to the project I am using:

- Service Account Token Creator
- Service Account User
- plus a custom role with the `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` assigned

I have generated a local JSON credential file using the following command line

```
gcloud auth application-default login --project=myprojectid --impersonate-service-account <svcacctname>@<application id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --scopes="openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.login,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

I have the following code in C# to try to upload a file (abbreviated for clarity):

```
using (var stream =
            new FileStream(@"C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        if (credentials.IsCreateScopedRequired)
        {
            credentials = credentials.CreateScoped(new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive });
        }


        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "myappid",
        });

        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        // Create a new file on drive.
        using (var stream = new FileStream(localFileName,
                    FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
            request = service.Files.Create(
                fileMetadata, stream, "audio/mp3");
            request.Fields = "id";
            IUploadProgress prog = request.Upload();

            if (prog.Exception != null)
            {
                // code arrives here
                Console.WriteLine(prog.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(request.ResponseBody);
            }

    }
```

I get the following exception/response:

```
Error:"{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
", Description:"", Uri:""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check that you created the service account on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

[How to create Google Oauth2 Service account credentials.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A)

Remember if you upload it like that its going to upload the file to the service accounts google drive account.

Comment: While this wasn't the complete answer your video on how to upload to Google drive with .Net did the trick (ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5b0ivBYqeQ). Sharing the folder with the service account was important and I re-created my credentials file per the video and it worked!